# White bar over menu bar?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, menu-bar, bug

I'm experiencing this weird bug on OS X El capitan.

There is a white bar over most of my menu items in the top right of my screen. The items are still there and are interactable.

Anyone got any ideas? A quick google search didn't seem to give me any ideas for it.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: I'm having this exact problem on Sierra with a 2016 MBP.  It only occurs when the external screen has no windows on it, so opening and closing a Finder window fixes it.  It's bizarre though that it's been around for so long and I'd love to know what's causing is.

Answer (score 6):

For me this happened on one of the monitors that I was extending my macbook pro's desktop to, not all of them though.

Easiest fix, expand a program to full screen and then minimize it again, somehow the animation of expanding fixes it.

Comment: This workaround works. Although I wonder what the cause is, and how to prevent it. Do you guys also use the Bartender app, by any chance? (it hides some icons from the Tray bar)

Answer (score 0):

In SystemPreferences->Display  set the Brightness lower.