# iTerm white bar showing over tabs

Tags: terminal, macos, iterm

Since upgrading to Sierra on my new 2017 MBP i've got a very annoying bug that I can't seem to find a solution for.

I've got a white bar showing over my iTerm window every time iTerm is the front-most in-focus app.

[image]

I tried the solution from this question but it didn't really help: [White bar over menu bar?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212339/white-bar-over-menu-bar?s=1|3.1476)